# Amadeus flight API authorization

Tags: flutter, amadeus

I am trying to use one of the Amadeus flight API (flight lowest-fare search) and I think I am having issues with the authorization. The first part of the authorization works fine where I have to input the grant type, API key, and API secret. This returns the access token needed to return the flight API. However, when printing the response body I keep getting null. Could someone help me with this? I am showing my API key and API secret but that's not an issue as I can create a new one. Here's the code:

To first provide context, here's how an Amadeus API gets called after access token is retrieved from the authorization server. This endpoint returns a flight's check-in links.

curl -X GET \
  "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/reference-data/urls/checkin-links?airlineCode=1X" \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer CpjU0sEenniHCgPDrndzOSWFk5mN"

I believe my issue might in my authorization header in the flight low-fare search endpoint. I concatenated the two variables in which the token_type which has a value of 'Bearer' and the access token. In the curl example, 'Bearer' is within the speech marks. In flutter, you cannot do that as 'Authorization is the only header. Below is my code in dart:

```
getFlights(fromCode, toCode) async {
// getting access token
var response = await http.post(
  'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token',
  body: {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "cxuxBmIvbpbv0JKzKTsJjNqc595uJVYb",
    "client_secret": "buhj4SDGVrG1AzzV",
  },
);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  try {
    print(response.body);
    var code = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (code != null) {
      var tokenType = code['token_type'];
      print(tokenType);
      print(code['access_token']);
      var token = code['access_token'];
      var bearerToken = '$tokenType ' + '$token';
      print(bearerToken);

      // flight low-fare search endpoint
      var flightApi = await http.get(
        'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=LHR&destination=CDG&departureDate=2020-03-19&max=2',
        headers: {
          "Authorization": bearerToken,

        });
      var flight = json.decode(response.body);
      print(flight['data']);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

}

This the return from the authorization server which provides the access token:

```
{
        "type": "amadeusOAuth2Token",
        "username": "I REMOVED THIS",
        "application_name": "I REMOVED THIS",
        "client_id": "cxuxBmIvbpbv0JKzKTsJjNqc595uJVYb",
        "token_type": "Bearer",
        "access_token": "z8rVGOAuGaXGNUMIcVPYW76ki5Dl",
        "expires_in": 1799,
        "state": "approved",
        "scope": ""
    }
```

This is the return for the flight low-fare search endpoint

```
flutter: null
```

Comment: What http code do you get? Do you get a message? I checked your credentials, they are working properly. The Low-fare Search call is working as well so yes it seems to be related to the way you put the authorization token.

Comment: Yes the problem was with the authorization token. I have figured it out already. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Don't forget to renew your API key/secret. On the other side, the Flight Low-fare Search API is deprecated and will be decommissionned soon to be replaced by the Flight Offers Search. The migration is quite easy, should you do it.